# How do I put AngularJS "required" in a slim form (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, slim-lang

I'm creating a form using AngularJS like this tutorial (http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation). I need to put AngularJS 'required' inside the inputs, but in Slim I do not know how to put it in.
I tried :input_html => {required} or :input_html => {'required'} or required or 'required' inside input element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write this:

```
:input_html => {:required => ""}
```

It worked for me!!

Comment: yeah! I tried :input_html => {'required' => ''} and it worked!